# ionic2: How to do calculations in form?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a form with product rate and quantity inputs. I need to calculate the value (rate * quantity) and assign the value to amount input field.

Please find the code snippet below:

```
  <form [formGroup]="additemForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(additemForm.value)" >

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list inset>            
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Product :</ion-label>
          <ion-select formControlName="product">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let product of productArray" value="{{product.code}}" selected="false">{{product.name}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>QUANTITY :</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" formControlName="qty"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>             
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>RATE:</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" formControlName="rate"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Value :</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" formControlName="value"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>                         
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="signup-col">
      <button ion-button class="submit-btn"  type="submit" [disabled]="!additemForm.valid">Submit</button>
      <button ion-button type="button" (click)='cancel()' >Cancel</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>      

  </form>
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[(ngModel)]` for this.

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>QUANTITY :</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="qty" [(ngModel)]="quantity"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>             
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>RATE:</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="rate" [(ngModel)]="rateValue"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Value :</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="value" [(ngModel)]="rateValue * quantity"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Now, still amount input field will be edible after this. And changing this value will affect the other 2 input values also. You can disable the input, so it will appear as a read-only input. This worked in my code.

Comment: Is there any events we can attach to the inputs so that we can calculate the value when the value is changed. For eg, the calculation may external data  which is not part of the form.

Comment: I want to know the exact use case. Like, exactly what are you trying to implement. From my understanding, not an event, but, `[(ngModel)]` is a 2 way binding. So, you can have these `quantity` and `rateValue` variables in your typescript. Try setting their values in typescript. It works.

Comment: Like I need to calculate the discount and tax based on the product selected in this case.

Comment: Yes. In that case, `[(ngModel)]` works fine. You will have that value in typescript as I have mentioned in the previous comment.